# How to slice the pandas dataframe which has date as its index

Tags: pandas, datetime, slice

I have pandas dataframe which reads like below

```
                SKU
1/1/2017        1
2/1/2017        2
3/1/2017        3
4/1/2017        4
5/1/2017        5
```

So it has date string as index 
How can I perform slicing operation for this dataframe

I tried

```
df.loc['1/1/2017':'3/1/2017']
```

It threw me error, saying that I have to convert the string indexes into datetime

Kindly help

Comment: For me it working nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it working nice with your sample data:

```
print (df.loc['1/1/2017':'3/1/2017'])
          SKU
1/1/2017    1
2/1/2017    2
3/1/2017    3
```

But I suggest create `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True)
print (df.loc['2017-01-01':'2017-01-03'])
            SKU
2017-01-01    1
2017-01-02    2
2017-01-03    3
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael , well noted :)